# Python colorama not working with replace method and input?

Tags: python, colorama

I am trying to code Wordle for my computer science course. However I can't seem to get it to work. Below is the code that I have so far.

```
while (playerTurns < 7 and win == False):
  
  guess = input("Guess a 5 letter word: ")
  while (len(guess) != 5):
    guess = input("Guess a 5 letter word: ")

  letterPosition = 0
  for i in guess:
    if (i == answer[letterPosition]):
      guess = guess.replace(i, Fore.GREEN + i, 1)
    elif (i in answer):
      guess = guess.replace(i, Fore.YELLOW + i, 1)
    letterPosition += 1
```

Whenever I run this I get something like this.
[non-working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3bGI.png)

I know that there have been other posts about this problem but none of the solutions seem to be working for me.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: you could use inner loop `for char in answer:` instead of `letterPosition += 1`

Comment: you replace only first matching char - maybe you always replace color in the same mathcin char. Besides, after adding `Fore.GREEN` to `guess` you may also check `if Fore.GREEN == answer[letterPosition]`. And sometimes it is wrong idea to update variable (`guess`) which you use in `for` - `for i in guess`

Comment: I checked `"not working code"` and it seems your code works but your terminal doesn't know how to display colors. If you run it in some IDE then it may use fake terminal and better run code in normal terminal/console.

Comment: `Fore.GREEN` doesn't change color for single char but for all chars after `Fore.GREEN` - so you should add `Fore.GREEN + i + Fore.White` or something like `Fore.GREEN + i + RESET`

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Instead of linking an image, please edit your post and type out the information.